# setup WebRTC peer connection when using electron and reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, webrtc

I am trying to build a desktop app which is about video calling using electron and reactjs and webRTC. I have used create-react-app so my electron related code will be inside public folder. I need help on setting up `RTCPeerConnection`. I have no idea where should i do this. Do i emit an event when the room is joined using `ipcRenderer.send('signal')` and then listen that in electron as `ipcMain.on("signal")` or there is other way.

Can anyone help me on this, please? I want to know the appropriate place to setup `RTCPeerConnection`.

Because i tried the above way as following but got an issue of `Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined at IpcEvents.startSignaling`

electron/ipc_events.js

```
startSignaling() {
  this.rtcPeerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(CONFIGURATION);
  console.log('this rtcPeerConn', this.rtcPeerConn);
}

ipcMain.on("signal", event => {
  if (!this.rtcPeerConn) {
    this.startSignaling();
  }
})
```

electron/main.js

```
const IpcEvents = require('./ipc_events');

class MainWindow extends BrowserWindow {
  constructor(dev, winState) {
    this.events = new IpcEvents(this);
    this.events.initiateListenEvents();
  }
}
```

If i check in console`RTCPeerConnection` then i dont get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use RTCPeerConnection in your main process. You have to move your logic in the renderer.

When you type console.log(RTCPeerConnection) in the console, you are logging the module API from the renderer, where it is accessible.